# Finetuning DNN with continuous outputs in the last layer

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

Greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out here:

I'm trying to do some finetuning on a regression task --- my inputs are `200X200` RGB images and my prediction output/label is a set of real values (let's say, within `[0,10]`, though scaling is not a big deal here...?) --- on top of `InceptionV3` architecture. Here are my functions that take a pretrained `Inception` model, remove the last layer and add a a new layer, set up for finetuning...

```
"""
Fine-tuning functions
"""
IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT = 299, 299 #fixed size for InceptionV3
NB_EPOCHS = 3
BAT_SIZE = 32
FC_SIZE = 1024
NB_IV3_LAYERS_TO_FREEZE = 172

def eucl_dist(inputs):
    x, y = inputs
    return ((x - y)**2).sum(axis=-1)

def add_new_last_continuous_layer(base_model):
  """Add last layer to the convnet
  Args:
    base_model: keras model excluding top, for instance:
    base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
  Returns:
    new keras model with last layer
  """
  x = base_model.output
  x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  x = Dense(FC_SIZE, activation='relu')(x) 
  predictions = Lambda(eucl_dist, output_shape=(1,))(x)
  model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=predictions)
  return model

def setup_to_finetune_continuous(model):
   """Freeze the bottom NB_IV3_LAYERS and retrain the remaining top 
layers.
   note: NB_IV3_LAYERS corresponds to the top 2 inception blocks in 
     the inceptionv3 architecture
   Args:
     model: keras model
   """
   for layer in model.layers[:NB_IV3_LAYERS_TO_FREEZE]:
      layer.trainable = False
   for layer in model.layers[NB_IV3_LAYERS_TO_FREEZE:]:
      layer.trainable = True
   model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.0001, momentum=0.9),   
             loss='eucl_dist')
```

Here are my implementations:

```
base_model = InceptionV3(weights = "imagenet", 
include_top=False, input_shape=(3,200,200))
model0 = add_new_last_continuous_layer(base_model)

setup_to_finetune_continuous(model0)

history=model0.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_data = (test_x, test_y), nb_epoch=epochs, batch_size=32)
scores = model0.evaluate(test_x, test_y, verbose = 0)
features = model0.predict(X_train)
```

where `train_x` is a `(168435, 3, 200, 200)` `numpy` array and `train_y` is a `(168435,)` `numpy` array. The same goes for `test_x` and `test_y` except the number of observations is `42509`.

I got the `TypeError: Tensor object is not iterable` bug which occurred at `predictions = Lambda(eucl_dist, output_shape=(1,))(x)'' when going through the`add_new_last_continuous_layer()`` function. Could you anyone kindly give me some guidance to get around that and what the problem is? Greatly appreciated and happy holidays!

EDIT:
Changed the functions to:

```
def eucl_dist(inputs):
    x, y = inputs
    return ((x - y)**2).sum(axis=-1)

def add_new_last_continuous_layer(base_model):
  """Add last layer to the convnet
  Args:
    base_model: keras model excluding top, for instance:
    base_model = InceptionV3(weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
  Returns:
    new keras model with last layer
  """
  x = base_model.output
  x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  x1 = Dense(FC_SIZE, activation='relu')(x) 
  x2 = Dense(FC_SIZE, activation='relu')(x) 
  predictions = Lambda(eucl_dist, output_shape=eucl_dist_shape)([x1,x2])
  model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=predictions)
  return model
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer learning with Eulidean loss in the final layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47984976/transfer-learning-with-eulidean-loss-in-the-final-layer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output shape for the lambda layer is wrong. Define your functions like this:

```
from keras import backend as K

def euclidean_distance(vects):
    x, y = vects
    return K.sqrt(K.maximum(K.sum(K.square(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True), K.epsilon()))


def eucl_dist_output_shape(shapes):
    shape1, shape2 = shapes
    return (shape1[0], 1)

predictions = Lambda(euclidean_distance, output_shape=eucl_dist_output_shape)([input1, input2])
```

Comment: Thanks so much a lot Nain! :D

Comment: Excuse my n00b question: are the input1 and input2 outputs from the base_model, or rather my training samples?

Comment: If I am not wrong, then you are using Euclidean distance as a similarity metric here. Then `input1 and input2` can be two training sample or even two data points. It's up to you how are your framing your problem

Comment: Thanks a lot Nain for such swift reply!! Excuse my newbiness once again >_<... I thought the Euclidean loss is applied to predicted scores vs ground truth scores... in which case the input 1 should be the output of the base_model --- the previous layers, and the input2 should be the groundtruth score?

Comment: In that case, why don't you use the `mse` itself as the loss function?

Comment: ah sorry I was wrong, I did need a Euclidean loss final layer, on top of the mse loss function... Did I miss anything...?

Comment: or is that redundant?

Comment: Obviously it's redundant

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help so far!! @Nain but which is redundant?? I have to use a Euclidean loss final layer since my ultimate prediction output is a real value... But then do I not need to change the loss function when compiling the model?